# How to concatenate multiple cells without typing each one and add a space after each value

Tags: microsoft-excel, concatenation

I have a list of hashtags that I would like to use in my Instagram posts.  I would like to make groupings of the hashtags so I can easily copy and paste them to my posts.

The hashtags are sorted by popularity, so ideally, I would like to do something like A1, A10, A20, A30, A40, A50, A60, then the next cell, I would concatenate A2, A11, A21...

Is there a way to achieve this easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have office 2019 or newer, the TEXTJOIN function would be useful, e.g.:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A1:A10)
```

Or for a non-continuous range:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A1,A10,A20,A30,...)
```

Or for some arbitrary selection or series (requires Office 365), e.g. every 10th row:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDEX(A1:A1000,MAKEARRAY(1,10,LAMBDA(r,c,c*10))))
```

Comment: This is exactly the sort of madness I was thinking would exist.

Comment: When I do this it skips the first 10 results and starts from row 11.  How can I do this so it also includes the first result and then skips 10?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I did was to concatenate a space to the end of my data.

```
=CONCATENATE(A1," ")
```

Then I did a formula manually.

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,A10,A20,A30,A40,A50,A60,A70,A80,A90)
```

Then all I had to do was fill down and it worked.